# Connect with Backend Server

Tags: rest, xamarin

I'm new in developing Xamarin app and I'm not a backend developer. I use VS 2017 to develop Mobile App.

Can anyone please give me links how to create a REST API (Json type) to connect with Backend server? I need to retrieve data from my company server.

The app will take many parameters as database name, table name and return a dataset of all the records. I know that the RESTful can be build for specific table but how can I code the RESTful API can take parameters as databases and tables bases on the input on my Xamarin app.

Please help. and how can I display the record in list view on Xamarin app as I did for my Android app. Thank you.

If you have other way to connect with .NET core server.Please tell me solution.

Comment: You can have a look at here: [rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Refit, install with nuget. They have very detailed docs and how to use:

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Answer (score 0):

You could use Restsharp for your problem: http://restsharp.org/. It's a easy to use and quite popular REST/HTTP Client Libary.